# Shell Script for creating directory

Tags: shell

I have a partition `/dev/sda3` and it is called `/share`.

```
$ df
/dev/sda3  /share
```

Now I need to write script to create directory called codedumps in /dev/sda3 but when I use the command

```
path "/share/"
mkdir $path"codedumps"
```

in shell script, it creates another directory inside `/share` partition called `share` and then inside that creates a directory `codedumps`. But I want it to create `codedumps` in `/share` partition itself it should be topmost directory in partition `/dev/sda3` (i.e `/share` partiiton).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
share="share"
mkdir /$share/"codedumps"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use path variable, its a unix variable.
cd

## Or navigate to directory and then create directory

cd $share 
mkdir codedumps

Comment: $path isn't a environment variable, $PATH is. (remember it's case sensitive)